# Problem displaying document.body.innerHTML.replace

Tags: javascript, datatables

I add **document.body.innerHTML** to the page, but the results are displayed incorrectly in the **inspect element**!

I will add this code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/xxxxxxx/g, 'sssssssssss');
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmcIW.png

But in the **inspect element** it shows this code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/sssssssssss/g, 'sssssssssss');
```

[inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kopyN.png)

Why does this happen?

I use datatables to display in the table, but I want to change the column title to another language

Comment: If you change the line to `document.body.innerHTML = 'foo';`, is it reflected on the page? Also, did you remove your browser cache? Is there a server static page cache?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the script is inside the body, so as a result, it is replacing all of that content in the script too. What you could do, is, put all of the front-end contents into a div element with a specific id. Then, get the innerHTML of that div, and it should work.

Have a good day!